# Flex CSS - margin-left on list items not just last-child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation-6

I'm slowly getting to grips with Flex but it has got me confused how I can make all li elements within a ul.list float right. I've read that in order to get the item floating right you simply use `margin-left: auto` however this only seems to work correctly on the last item, because when I resize the viewpoint to above 1920px or above the gap between the email and telephone number increases... while the left side of the top menu but remains the same distance between each li element.

*Here is my HTML:*

```
<header class="ProMenu">
  <nav class="row align-middle expanded">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns Links">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" title="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" title="">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns Logo">
      <a href="" title=""><img src="https://placehold.it/64x42" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-4 columns Contact">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="tel:" title="">Phone: 0777123456</a></li>
        <li><a href="mailto:" title="">Email: jog@blogs.com</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> 
  </nav>
</header>
```

*And my CSS:*

```
.ProMenu {
    background: #0071c5;
    width: 100%;
}
.ProMenu .row {
    min-height: 60px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.ProMenu ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
.ProMenu .Logo {
    text-align: center;
}
.Contact ul li{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

*JSFiddle:*

And to make things easier I've uploaded the code to a [online JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SimonHayter/28btx50v/), to replicate make the window big and monitor the distance between both the mobile number and email increases... something that I want to stop.

Comment: Hi @Michael_B yes thank you... your method works but I accepted the other Michael's answer purely on the fact that it uses already built in classes to serve this process. Thanks for your time.;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to utilize the foundation `.align-right` class, which will apply `justify-content: flex-end;`

https://jsfiddle.net/28btx50v/2/

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `margin-left: auto` from the last child. Put it only on the second to last child. That will force both elements to the right.

When a flex item has `margin-left: auto`, it pushes itself away from everything on its left. In your case, that makes sense for the second to last child. But it doesn't make sense for the last child.

That's why when you widen the screen you get a wider separation between the two.

By using `margin-left: auto` only on the second to last item, you pack both items together and everything shifts right. You can then use regular (numerical) horizontal margins, if necessary, to create space between them.